# How to fetch the data from database when click on the images

Tags: php, mysql

I dont no how to fetch the data from database when click on the thumnail images  and displaying the enlarge image and correspondingly displaying that description of that particular image

so please help me

Comment: This is a general question that means you need to do some research into the general workings of, amongst other things, AJAX and PHP. There's plenty of resources on both if you have a look around. If, then, you try something and have a specific question, we can help.

Comment: You have any existing implementation you have done ??? It would be better if we help you work on that

Answer (score 1):

you can set a link on the thumbnail to a detail page with the informations or you can use an ajax call to get the information from another php script and then display it in an overlay or wherever you want